# i've two columns in dataframe "First Response Time (HH:MM:SS) and "Target" with values "00:08:40" and "00:25:00" while subtracting im facing error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to subtract the first response from the target, if the output is less than target it has to add "INSLA" in new column of the data frame. I'm getting an error as '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'.  How to change both of them to integer values.?

I've tried with code

tickets['SLA'] = np.where(tickets['First Response Time (HH:MM:SS)']< tickets['Target'],"INSLA","OSLA")

```
report = pd.read_excel('9999.xlsx',index_col=0)

report['Requester'] = report['Requester'].str.replace(" ","")  # removes 
space from requester columns
report['Requester']= report['Requester'].str.lower() # converts names to 
lowercase
df = pd.DataFrame(report)

tickets['Target'] = np.where(tickets['Priority'] =="High" ,'00:25:00',
                    np.where(tickets['Priority'] == "Medium",'00:30:00',
                     np.where(tickets['Priority'] == "Normal",'00:30:00',
                      np.where(tickets['Priority']== "Low",'00:30:00',
                       np.where(tickets['Priority'] == "Critical", 
'00:10:00',tickets['Priority'])))))

tickets['SLA'] = np.where(tickets['First Response Time (HH:MM:SS)']< 
tickets['Target'],"INSLA","OSLA")
```

the expected output is "INSLA" if first response is less than Target or "OSLA"

Actual Result is :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/python work space/webScraping/report/test2.py", line 76, in

```
tickets['SLA'] = np.where(tickets['First Response Time (HH:MM:SS)']< tickets['Target'],"INSLA","OSLA")
```

File "C:\Users\Kittu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1735, in wrapper

```
res_values = na_op(self.values, other.values)
```

File "C:\Users\Kittu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1625, in na_op

```
result = _comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, x, y)
```

File "C:\Users\Kittu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1601, in _comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY

```
result = libops.vec_compare(x, y, op)
```

File "pandas_libs\ops.pyx", line 164, in pandas._libs.ops.vec_compare
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Can you add sample of your data? Maybe you need to change column type to int like this: `df[col_name] = pd.to_numeric(df[col_name])`. You can check column types using `df.dtypes`

Comment: I tried with your code it is still giving the error 


  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/webScraping/report/test2.py", line 78, in <module>
    tickets['First Response Time (HH:MM:SS)'] = pd.to_numeric(tickets['First Response Time (HH:MM:SS)'])
  File "C:\Users\Kittu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py", line 135, in to_numeric
    coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric)

  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 1925, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric

ValueError: Unable to parse string "0:08:40" at position 0

Comment: Do you want to compare dates or ints?

Comment: Actually I want to compare time stamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before comparing dates you have to convert columns to datetime type:

```
tickets['First Response Time (HH:MM:SS)'] = pd.to_datetime(tickets['First Response Time (HH:MM:SS)'], format='%H:%M:%S')
tickets['Target'] = pd.to_datetime(tickets['Target'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

(here I suppose that `Target` column is the same format as `First Response Time (HH:MM:SS)`)

Comment: Tried with your code still facing error both columns are in the same format

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/python work space/webScraping/report/test2.py", line 77, in <module>
 File "C:\Users\Kittu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 261, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 153, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
ValueError: time data 0 does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: Can you post example of your data? Error says that format is different

Comment: First Response Time (HH:MM:SS)
00:09:57
00:17:00

Target
00:25:00
00:25:00


For target values i did 

tickets['Target'] = np.where(tickets['Priority'] =="High" ,'00:25:00',
                        np.where(tickets['Priority'] == "Medium",'00:30:00'))

Comment: Can you check if there are any None values?

Comment: yeah there are few zero values in First Response Time (HH:MM:SS) column

Comment: You can set some default values (like '00:00:00') instead of zeros to match required format like this: `tickets['First Response Time (HH:MM:SS)'] = tickets['First Response Time (HH:MM:SS)'].replace({0: '00:00:00'})`

Comment: while converting to time stamp it is coming like  01-01-1900  00:04:54  is there any option to get only time without date like (00:04:54).

Comment: Yes, you can add `.dt.time` to the end of lines while converting to_datetime, example: `tickets['Target'] = pd.to_datetime(tickets['Target'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time`